# Javascript closures and rails 5 Can't find local variables

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

The code below works in jsfiddle and other places but in my rails 5 app I keep getting can't find variable error.  I don't know how javascript closures could be effecting things.  I've put the javascript in the assets but that didn't help. I am trying to make an equation editor for a quiz app. I am a high school math teacher -- pretty rusty on javascript stuff. This code is from Mathjax doc pages. I can get plain latex to render on this page with mathjax just not the closure function stuff.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>MathJax Dynamic Math Test Page</title>

<script src="/MathJax/MathJax.js">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
    jax: ["input/TeX","output/HTML-CSS"],
    tex2jax: {inlineMath: [["$","$"],["\\(","\\)"]]}
  });
</script>

</head>
<body>

<script>
  //
  //  Use a closure to hide the local variables from the
  //  global namespace
  //
 (function () {
    var QUEUE = MathJax.Hub.queue;  // shorthand for the queue
    var math = null;                // the element jax for the math    output.

    //
//  Get the element jax when MathJax has produced it.
//
QUEUE.Push(function () {
  math = MathJax.Hub.getAllJax("MathOutput")[0];
});

//
//  The onchange event handler that typesets the
//  math entered by the user
//
window.UpdateMath = function (TeX) {
  QUEUE.Push(["Text",math,"\\displaystyle{"+TeX+"}"]);
}
 })();
```

```
Type some TeX code:
<input id="MathInput" size="50" onchange="UpdateMath(this.value)" />
<p>

<div id="MathOutput">
You typed: ${}$
</div>

</body>
</html>
```